# How to run the currently opened file from Notepad++ in it's default application?

Tags: notepad++, default

I'm editing JSFL files, and I would like to quickly run those after I save them.

Is it possible to configure Notepad++ to use a Keyboard Shortcut to open the current file (being edited) in it's default application? (In this case Adobe Flash Pro CS6).

If it's possible to have a Run command that is generic enough to work as a "Run in Default Application" action as opposed to having to configure each individual file-types to their respective default Application, that would be the best solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Actually, found my own solution.

Adding a new "**Run...**" command does the trick!

Instructions:

- Click the Menu "**Run** -> **Run**..." (or alternatively hit F5)
- Enter "**$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)**" in the field (without quotes)
- Click "**Save...**"
- Give it a name (ex: "**Run in Default App**")
- **OPTIONAL**: Assign it a *Keyboard Shortcut* (ex: **CTRL+SHIFT+F5**)

Enjoy!

Comment: From the sourceforge page [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=External_Programs) is the list of how to do other stuff

Comment: Is this equivalent to double-clicking the file? My file is a ps1. Double-clicking this Powershell Script opens it in Notepad; it doesn't run it. So I made sure to change my "Open With" default for ps1 types to use the Powershell exe. Doesn't work how I'd expect. Hmm...

Comment: Hmm here's an idea (haven't tested), try prepending 'start' to the Run field, so it turns out like `start $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`. Not sure if Notepad++ actually runs this field in the command-line, but it might work.

Comment: Nvm, just tried it with "start" and no dice. You may need to track down where the Powershell Script executable is located and prepend the command with it (ex: `C:\Program Files\Powershell\powershell.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`). Alternatively, you can add the Powershell location to your System Environment Variable PATH (Not sure if Powershell does it by default).

Comment: 'Chrome $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)', From your answer, I got an inspiration to specify a particular software to open, for example, using Chrome to open.

Answer (score 4):

Menu -> Run (or F5 shortcut key)

`cmd /k cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" && "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Click "Save..." button

This will allow you to see debug info if the script fails (thinking of a python script here). The /k switch prevent cmd from exiting. Changing to current path is important, otherwise os.path.exist('./somefile') won't work.

Comment: It might be useful to change `cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"` to `cd /d "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"` to ensure this always works regardless of drive.